# Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.3.0-alpha02 when updating to 1.3.0-alpha02

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to test latest version of jetpack compose 1.3.0-alpha02 ([Changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.3.0-alpha02)). So I created a new project and updated the version to `1.3.0-alpha02`

But when running it, I get this error like something's not found:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.3.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.3.0-alpha02/compiler-1.3.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.3.0-alpha02/compiler-1.3.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

What is the reason? I did nothing special. Just updated the version

Answer (score 5):

There's something you missed to look at

Although when you create a **Template compose project** using Android studio, **it assumes that both `compose libs` and `compose-compiler` are the same version**, but for `1.3.0-alpha01` it's different

From [**Release note**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose):
[image: release note screenshot]

You should see that `compose-compiler` version is `1.3.0-rc02`

So go and update it:

```kotlin
// app/build.gradle
composeOptions {
    // kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version // Change this
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.3.0-rc02" // to this
}
```

And then retry syncing

### TL; DR

Generally, the version of **Compose libraries** might be different than `compose-compiler`, so when adding them, make sure you add the proper version.

Comment: "When going with the preview version, the version of Compose libraries might be different than compose-compiler" It's not only for preview version. Compose compiler has officially moved to it's own independent versioning. So he can safely assume that from now on it will always have a different version from compose libraries